# Ошибка вместо предупреждения? E1002 Symbol 'TThreadPriority' is specific to a platform

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

Код  в delphi 10.1 berlin
 выдает 3 одинаковые ошибки.
 В других файлах для 'TThreadPriority' были W1002 такие же но варнинги. 
 ОС win7 x32

```
[dcc32 Error] unit1.pas(80): E1002 Symbol 'TThreadPriority' is specific to a platform

   IServiceThread = interface( IUnknown )
     [ _IID_IServiceThread ]

     function Get_Priority(): TThreadPriority; stdcall;
     procedure Set_Priority(value: TThreadPriority); stdcall;

     property Priority: TTHreadPriority read Get_Priority write Set_Priority;

    end;
```

в модуле какая нужна специальная что-ли опция компилятора?
или в настройках проекта? 
в файле System.Classes определено так.

```
   {$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
     TThreadPriority = (tpIdle, tpLowest, tpLower, tpNormal, tpHigher, tpHighest,
       tpTimeCritical) platform;
    {$ENDIF MSWINDOWS}
```

Comment: Проверьте, какая целевая платформа для компиляции у вас выбрана и поддерживает ли она данный класс?